# How to access selectInput values in function.R file in shiny dashboard

Tags: shiny

I am developing a shiny app where user uploads a csv file and on action button click event file will be pushed to mysql database. I am using 3 files `ui.R,server.R` and `function.R`

Here is my `ui.R` file looks like

```
tabItem("chooseFile",
          fluidRow(
            box(
              width = 5, status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE,
              title = "Send Emails",
              helpText(tags$b("Please uplaod .csv or .tsv file")),
              tags$hr(),
              fileInput('csv_file', 'Choose file to upload',
                        accept = c(
                          'text/csv',
                          'text/comma-separated-values',
                          'text/tab-separated-values',
                          'text/plain',
                          '.csv',
                          '.tsv'
                        )
              ),
              tags$hr(),
              checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
              radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                           c(Comma=',',
                             Semicolon=';',
                             Tab='\t'),
                           ','),
              actionButton("upload_file", tags$b("Upload File"))


              )
            )
          ),
```

Here is my `server.R` file

```
 observeEvent(input$upload_file, {
     csv <- input$csv_file
     saveData(csv)
     session$sendCustomMessage(type ='testmessage',
                               message = paste0("File has been successfully uploaded to database"))

   })
```

Following is my `saveData()` function looks like which is in `function.R` file

```
saveData <- function(data) {
    # Connect to the database
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host, 
              port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)
    # Construct the update query by looping over the data fields
    dbWriteTable(db, table, input$csv, overwrite = TRUE)

    dbDisconnect(db)

    return(final_data)
  }
```

`input$csv` is file I want to upload in a database,but when I run this code it gives me following error.

```
Error in dbWriteTable(db, table, input$csv_file, overwrite = TRUE) : 
object 'input' not found
```

How do I access input variable from `ui.R` file in `function.R` file ?

Comment: From what I see you don't have any input named csv. So I guess or you should use input$csv_file in the function call, or remove the input$ part in the dbWriteTable and pass the csv variable to the function call.

Comment: @ValterBeaković  Now I am getting this error `Error in dbWriteTable(db, table, data) :  argument "data" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Not at my Pc now, will take a look later today

Comment: Does each of the uploaded files has to be stored as a separate table in the database?

Comment: @ValterBeaković  No, it will go in the same table.

Comment: you need to load the `function.R` file in your `sever.R` file with `source("PATH TO FILE, local = T)`

Answer (score 1):

I am finally able to do it with following code.

```
data <- reactive({
inFile <- input$csv_file 
if (is.null(inFile)){
  return(NULL)}
data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, encoding = 'UTF-8')
data
```

})

I can access it globally with `data()`